# simple user defined class with operator = overloading code crashed

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

I am testing a simple operator overloading code, when testing it, this piece of code just crashes (core dumped) at "nd.print()". Any suggestion?

The crash happens on ubuntu 16.04 64 bit. When I tried on some of online shell environment, such as https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler, it seems ok.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node
{
    int d;
    public:
    Node (int dd = 0):d(dd){}
    Node &operator=(Node &nd){ d = nd.d; }
    void print(){ cout<<d<<endl; }
};

int main()
{
    Node nd1(1), nd2(2);
    Node nd;
    nd = nd2 = nd1;
    nd.print();    //*******Crash here
    return 0;
}
```

I expect it just print a value without crashing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `operator=` method needs to return the assigned variable. As it is, it's not returning anything (although the signature says you will - you probably have a compiler warning about it), so the `nd = ...` bit is assigning an undefined value. You then try and call the `print` method on that undefined value.

In this case, you want to return the assigned value, which is `*this`:

```
Node &operator=(Node &nd)
{
    d = nd.d;
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: You should specify what should be returned, i.e. `return *this;`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Part of me wants to argue that the real answer is to check compiler warnings :)

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. I should have checked that carefully. Unfortunately, compiler does not give any warning.

Comment: @CloudGuy I don't have access to a Linux box right now (I'm at work) but Visual Studio gives an error, and trying it in another online C++ compiler suggests that g++ would return a warning https://godbolt.org/z/P6wf4Q